# Подключение к базе данных neo4j Python

Tags: python, neo4j

Подключаюсь к бд Neo4j

```
from py2neo import Graph , Node, Relationship
uri = "bolt://localhost:11007"
graph = Graph(uri, auth=("neo4j", "password"))
```

Ошибка такая

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\PycharmProjects\parsing\venv\lib\site packages\py2neo\database.py", 
line 88, in __new__inst = cls._instances[key]
KeyError: '7824b8eafc4c4213935d512d9cc25739'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/PycharmProjects/parsing/neo.py", line 6, in <module>
graph = Graph(uri, auth=("neo4j", "password"))
File "C:\PycharmProjects\parsing\venv\lib\site- 
packages\py2neo\database.py", line 305, in __new__
database = Database(uri, **settings)
File "C:\PycharmProjects\parsing\venv\lib\site- 
packages\py2neo\database.py", line 92, in __new__
from py2neo.internal.http import HTTPDriver, HTTPSDriver
File "C:\PycharmProjects\parsing\venv\lib\site- 
packages\py2neo\internal\http.py", line 26, in <module>
from neo4j.addressing import SocketAddress
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'neo4j.addressing'
```

В чем проблема ?

Comment: попробуйте [так](https://github.com/technige/py2neo/issues/711)

Comment: ничего не изменилось

Comment: А как вы назвали скрипт, который пытаетесь запускать? Не `neo4j.py` случаем?